# Did Hannibal make coins while campaigning using captured precious metals, Roman coins and perhaps bronze statues?

Tags: roman-empire, numismatics

The process of minting coins at the time would be similar to the Roman method and I assume it would have been normal for any large army to carry the required tools and craftsmen while campaigning to melt down captured material, coinage etc to generate his own coinage to pay the troops.  Rather than say pay the troops in coins looted from the Romans bearing the image of Roman emperors and gods.

> Metal was heated in a hot fire or furnace. It was either melted into a liquid and poured into molds, or softened and rolled into large sheets, which were then pounded into shape on an anvil. Specialist tools were needed, such as tongs to hold the metal sheets and hammers for all that pounding and flattening. [*TheCollector.com*](https://www.thecollector.com/ancient-roman-coins-how-were-they-made/)

Comment: @MCW Hannibal had a lot of mercenary troops and mercenaries want to be paid regularly. I don't know if Hannibal minted coins, but for sure he needed regular provisions of money.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes Hannibal did mint several coins from pillaged loot while he was in italy, these coins were mainly used to pay mercenaries and to bribe city officials. He minted many different coins in different denominations and metal contents.  One such coin that has been identified were the Quarter Shekels minted at a military mint in S. Italy - [link and pic](https://www.ngccoin.com/news/article/9401/)

Additionally, Hannibal minted electrum coins in capua during his control there. These coins had an obverse of a janiform head and reverse of zeus.  These coins were minted with the same metallurgical ratios and styles of those in Carthage and they were minted according to the carthage weighting system and not romes.

[image]

"COINS STRUCK BY HANNIBAL IN ITALY", Percy Gardner,
The Numismatic Chronicle and Journal of the Numismatic Society
Third Series, Vol. 4 (1884), pp. 220-224.

Comment: This is 100% correct.